# Creating animations in Android

Tags: android, animation

I'm creating an Android application that would need to have a layout on the left side of the screen with buttons listed beneath each other.

The user should be able to drag the layout in and out from the side, like you can see on the Samsung Omnia.

[image]

Could anyone please give me an example of this or any tips on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) ui component. Out of the box this comes with the ability to be dragged from the bottom via the "handle" to the top. In the main content area you can display a good variety of Views. The Handle can also be customised.

"So how does this help me?"

Look at the source for the SlidingDrawer and make an extension. There are some existing implementations, which is where I would start. Some examples:

- http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-sliding-drawer/
- http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622

I prefer the top implemtation, take a look at the newer stuff in the link on post, which will lead you to checkout some code from github.

References: [Android - Making Sliding Drawer to slide from Left-to-Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right)