# Activity over Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, slidetoggle

I'm kinda stuck here.

I need to set up something like facebook menu style. 
Or put an activity over other activity (slide it from one side, and stop it at some point - while doing that, the lower activity (view/layout) also needs to move).

I know how to put layout on top of other (change its visibility to gone/visible).
I found out how to scroll them.

But I need this for a bunch of activities, to have the same menu, and putting a bunch of code in every class, every .java file, every .xml file - that just isn't good. :(
Could you please help me? =)

I just need some ideas, on how to do that.

Oh. Is there a posibility to have one activity all the time in the background (that menu I need), and then on click on some button on upper activity (the upper screen that will be changing all the time), just slide upper activity to some positin, and than set focus on lower activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use a SlidingDrawer for sliding a layout like the notification system in Android.
See that for example : [Android - Making Sliding Drawer to slide from Left-to-Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right)

Comment: hmm. saw that one. but, I see that it's hard to work with, and it doesn't move my activity, it just goes on top of it.
is there a way, to fix that? =)