# how to insert a SlidingDrawer lateral?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I would like to include in my layout a SlidingDrawer, but I'd place it sideways on my layout. So That  the opening is from left to right instead of from the bottom upwards.How can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right) might help you creating horizontal sliding drawer. If you are using LinearLayout check once by making its orientation to horizontal