# Sliding Drawer Android

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I have used android:rotation="180" to make the sliding drawer horizontal to appear on left of screen. It works fine. But, the contents appears upside down in it because of the rotation. I tried to rotate the content layout also, but it gets rotated only after the sliding drawer is completely open. Please check my code attached with this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView LV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String [] List =  {"item 1","item 2","item 3","item 4"};
    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, List);
    LV.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:content="@+id/listView1"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rotation="180" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Handle" />

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:rotation="180"
     tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" >
  </ListView>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented a complete replacement for the SlidingDrawer component and it works from any side/direction. see http://www.github.com/kedzie/DraggableDrawers for details.

Now available from Maven Central ( [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin) ):

```
<dependency>
  <groupid>com.github.kedzie.draggabledrawers</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nice library.Thanks. I would try this out to check if this will work when the drawerlayouts are on top of one another and handles are one below the other.

Comment: FOr the record a single DragLayout can hold multiple drawers. But stacking should work just fine as touch events are only intercepted if you are actually dragging a drawer.  Also FYI I've added edge dragging functionality.. checkout the latest on the website http://kedzie.github.io/DraggableDrawers.

Comment: @mark.kedzierski i cant find your sliding drawer code. Where is it ? The link isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [THIS](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-sliding-drawer/) tutorial. You don't need to rotate the drawer...

Comment: I have seen that link before. But that is not a sliding drawer. It just hides / pops a particular transparent layout. And that can not serve me with the sliding effect.

Comment: You can add the slider effect too by passing an Animation!

Comment: oh. okay. Thanks. But, That seems a bit cumbersome for a beginner :( All I want to do is show a list of strings inside that. I will give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `android:gravity="left"` instead of rotation

Comment: Where do you want me to use the above statement? sorry, but I don't think it works for me.