# Layout issue on Sliding Drawer

Tags: android, layout, slidingdrawer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an Android SlidingDrawer slide out from the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137350/how-to-make-an-android-slidingdrawer-slide-out-from-the-left)

I have two Sliding Drawer Button which is on same side 
i want another sliding drawer to be on left side 
I have snippet 
[image]

What i have done is in xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <SlidingDrawer     android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_height="60dip">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:background="@drawable/projectmain"></Button>
            <LinearLayout android:background="@null" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <SlidingDrawer android:gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="left" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer1" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton1" android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_height="60dip">
        <Button android:gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="left"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton1" android:background="@drawable/propertymain"></Button>
            <LinearLayout android:background="@null" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please have a look in layout Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an Android SlidingDrawer slide out from the left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137350/how-to-make-an-android-slidingdrawer-slide-out-from-the-left). Also check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right

Comment: i didnt find any good post i have  tried everything but it is still on right