# How we can use slider Drawer from left to right orientation in Android

Tags: android, slider

How we can use slider Drawer from left to right flow in Android Tablet.
by default slider  flow from bottom to top, but when we give horizontal orientation  to it , it's flow of sliding  will be right to left .
But i need it's flow from left to right.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right
this is exact duplicate of your question.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Do you need something like this..

```
 <com.example.example.SlidingDrawer
     xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.example"
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="301dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     my:content="@+id/content"
     my:direction="leftToRight"
     my:handle="@+id/handle" >
      <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/handle"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:src="@drawable/tags"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/slidimage"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:padding="10dp" >
</LinearLayout>
    </com.example.example.SlidingDrawer>
```

[Here you can find example.](http://seasonofrejoice.blogspot.in/2013/01/sliding-drawer-in-android.html)

Comment: you need some thing like this

Comment: where is the class com.example.example.SlidingDrawer

Comment: How can I make action in sliding drawer