# sliding drawer doesn't perfectly work

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

slider is work from left to right but their content not display perfectly.
  any new idea or way to use slider to overlap main screen like sliding drawer.

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:rotation="180" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slideButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="180" >
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:rotation="180" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Option1" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Option2" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Option3" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Option4" >
        </Button>
     </LinearLayout>
   </SlidingDrawer>
```

slider display on same screen .
   thank you in advance

Comment: Please go through this link here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393755/how-we-can-use-slider-drawer-from-left-to-right-orientation-in-android
You might find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Android - Making Sliding Drawer to slide from Left-to-Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right)

[How we can use slider Drawer from left to right orientation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393755/how-we-can-use-slider-drawer-from-left-to-right-orientation-in-android)

There are some references you can gr through this.