# What Library and widgets should I use in order to develop a kind of side-sliding bar?

Tags: android-custom-view, slidingdrawer

I want to develop something like this
[Pic of a side sliding bar](http://oi59.tinypic.com/qsp0dk.jpg)

I have researched and there are ressources like NavigationDrawer and ActionBarSherlock for similar Tasks but I haven't found anything like this. SlidingDrawer could help but I have read, it's yet deprecated, isn't it? So, is there anything actual?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have looked around and I found approaches to implement what I want
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793194/android-making-sliding-drawer-to-slide-from-left-to-right) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393755/how-we-can-use-slider-drawer-from-left-to-right-orientation-in-android).