# How to do Android - Sliding Drawer to slide from Left-to-Right..?

Tags: android, android-sliding

How to put android sliding Drawer to slide from LTR?
When using `android:orientation="horizontal"` it slide from RTL.
How can I do LTR?
Thanks

................................

**I found answer form** [Here](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/)

Thanks everybody

Comment: I didn't find possible way from Google. anyway before ask question here I am always Google it.

Comment: How about just doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137350/how-to-make-an-android-slidingdrawer-slide-out-from-the-left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement your own SlidingDrawer.

There is no simple way to let it slide from the left like by changing some settings.

Check out these links:[Panel](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622) and [android-sliding-drawer](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-sliding-drawer/).

Comment: i found answer from http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/    thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try next widget 
https://github.com/xPutnikx/SlidingDrawerWithButtons

make it left to right, or another directions.