# How to create a sidebar in android

Tags: android, xml, sidebar

I developing a android application which required a sidebar as like as samsung sidebar. The sidebar contains multiple controls respectively.

For reference:
http://www.thinkdigit.com/FCKeditor/uploads/samsung-corby-s3650-2.jpg

Answer (score 7):

Please take a look at the Sliding Drawer concept in android. You can make use of it to develop the sidebar.

[Sliding Drawer.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

[How to make an Android SlidingDrawer slide out from the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137350/how-to-make-an-android-slidingdrawer-slide-out-from-the-left)

http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/sliding-drawer-again.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the [Sliding Drawer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) is now deprecated since API Level 17.

The current way to do this seems to be using [Drawer Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) to create a [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), which can be used by interacting with the Top Navigation button (the hamburger) or well by swiping from the left of the screen.

If you want you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460946/how-to-open-side-bar-on-icon-click-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821532/how-to-open-navigation-drawer-with-no-actionbar-open-with-just-a-button) questions for more details and information.

Answer (score 0):

Its a listview placed within  a sliding  drawer you can add items in listview and scroll it
hidding and unhidding part is done by slidding drawer