# How to open Navigation Drawer with no actionbar, open with just a button

Tags: android, button, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a navigation bar without any actionbar (I don't want an actionbar). I'm trying to make it so that I have a button that can open the navigation drawer.

I know there's a method called openDrawer for the DrawerLayout 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(android.view.View)

I didn't know how to use it, but i have tried making a button when click, runs this method:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLayout);
```

When i click it on it, it gives me a Java NullPointerException. Anybody has any idea?

EDIT:
This code is inside a fragment, and I'm trying to refer those drawer layout outside the fragment. I used debugger, and it is showing that mDrawlerLayout is NULL.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's giving you a null pointer because you are trying to find the drawer layout in the fragment's view, when it is actually in the activities view.

A quick hack to do what you want is to find the view like:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
```

That should work. A better way is to have a method on the activity for opening the drawer

```
public void openDrawer(){
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLayout);
}
```

In the activity onCreate run your findViewById:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

mDrawerLayout should be a member variable of your activity.

Then in your fragment you can call:

```
//cast activity to MyActivity so compiler doesn't complain
((MyActivity)getActivity()).openDrawer();
```

An even better way to do it is to create a listener in the fragment and set the activity as a listener to the fragment. Then you can call a method on the activity, similar to above. I'll let you do some research on how to do that.

Comment: I had to use `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);` in `openDrawer` method to make it work. (I am using navigation drawer without both fragments & action bar) Otherwise, it just hangs the app.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the default icon? In that position I want to use a different option menu.

Answer (score 40):

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
```

Answer (score 4):

**It works on Button click**

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @athor & @Ashish Tana.

It took me so much time to figure out the error (`NullPointerException`) I am getting.

Mine works this way; Instead of `getView()`, I use `getActivity()` and open the drawer by `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
final ImageButton btnOpenDrawer = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_menu);

        btnOpenDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
```

Comment: this really work I place this onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //place the code here
}

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler solution which uses [`isDrawerOpen()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout) of `DrawerLayout`.

The code below closes or opens the navigation drawer based on the drawer's current state (Opened/Closed)

```
Button hamMenu = findViewById(R.id.ham_menu);
hamMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DrawerLayout navDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // If navigation drawer is not open yet, open it else close it.
        if(!navDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) navDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        else navDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
    }
});
```

Comment: For close the drawer I had to use `navDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);` to make it work. Otherwise, I just get an _IllegalArgumentException_ because "No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18199771/880349

```
   //For me a better way in avoiding a `null pointer` in getting the DrawerLayout
   final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //Opens the Drawer
                drawer.openDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);
            }

                return false;
        });
```

You directly get the current drawer inside a view/fragement so that you won't get a *NullPointerException*

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Solution** 
If you want to open it from a fragment, you can use:

```
activity?.drawerLayout?.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
```

or inside the activity directly:

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
```

Note:
If you are not familiar with the '?', I highly recommend reading about null saftey from kotlin's documentation (It is very short don't worry): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html