# How to open Drawer Layout only with button?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm working on application that has a tab structure, and use sliding movements to move through the tabs.

But now, I want to apply Drawer Layout. The problem is that the Drawer has slide to open events. How I can delete this event? My idea was that the Drawer only could open and close with a button. Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: hello, did you manage to open the drawer by clicking on tab's button? please let me know thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just write

```
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

to prevent menu from listening to gesture

and use `openDrawer` and `closeDrawer` to change menu visibility

Comment: what would be the (int gravity arg) to open the drawer

Comment: @AbdulWahab  Gravity.LEFT or Gravity.RIGHT for RTL.
Gravity.START/Gravity.END from API 14

Answer (score 16):

By default the *DrawerLayout* is initially hidden from the view unless you put a code to open the `Drawer`, by the time there is a sliding event triggered.

From the [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) example, the contain `content_frame` is used to dynamically display views inside the `Drawer` using fragments.

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

From the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` you can include a button somewhere that has `OnClickListener` where in you put this code,

```
   //For me a better way in avoiding a `null pointer` in getting the DrawerLayout
   final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //Opens the Drawer
                drawer.openDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);
            }

                return false;
        });
```

You Can also use* to close the drawer.

```
drawer.closeDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did want to show the ActionBar. So I hide it, added a button to main layout and implemeneted openDrawer and closeDrawer methods. thanks @lordzden

Comment: What do u mean by this listView in 'drawer.openDrawer(Your View, Usually a ListView);' @lordzden

Answer (score 1):

**you can write this way**

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            drawer.openDrawer(navigationView);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate between drawer item on click of button inside your fragments,
you can use this

```
((YourMainActivity)getActivity()).selectItem(position);
```