# Manually Show ExpandableListView

Tags: android

How to show ExpandableListView manually if i touch a button. So far, the only way i can open it is by sliding the screen.

I couldn't find any method like show() like on Toast. I've tried looking for any similar sound method on android reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [scrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) method to scroll to a postion.
For open/ close a group, you can use [expand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Turns out, i was wrong. I should've animate the container. In this case, the drawer.

I got my answer from here. [How to open Drawer Layout only with button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141978/how-to-open-drawer-layout-only-with-button)

I just need to call opendrawer().