# Navigation Drawer without Actionbar

Tags: android, android-navigation

I searched many sites (stackoverflow as well) but couldn't understand how to implement the navigation drawer without the action bar. I know that this question has already been asked here but it doesn't have a proper explanation and code. I am a beginner in android development so can anyone please explain me with code **How to make a navigation drawer without an action bar**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: getSupportActionBar().hide()

Comment: @Vazeer Can you please help me out with the code as on other sites it's too complicated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open Navigation Drawer with no actionbar, open with just a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821532/how-to-open-navigation-drawer-with-no-actionbar-open-with-just-a-button)

Comment: @ChinmayDabke in this example http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html add  getActionBar().hide(); works for me

Comment: @VazeerThanks Vazeer. Will this work on API 10?

Comment: Great question, unfortunately the answers doesn't understood what it was questioned

Answer (score 22):

Just add your `DrawerLayout` like @mohan did, then if you have a button or something you tap on and want to open the drawer, just do like this :

```
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

and to close :

```
drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Comment: Android Studio prefer to use Gravity.START instead of Gravity.LEFT. because of in some locales typing left to right it gives rendering issue.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from the Sample Android NavigationDrawer app:

1. Use the Activity theme: Theme.NoTitleBar
2. Erase all the ActionBar references in the code
3. Create a button and in the clickListener call:

   drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

Comment: Used this approach and it worked with me , thanks for the steps @Kim Sant

Comment: Use `drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)` .