# How to show/Hide Navigation Drawer programmatically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can I use button to show/hide Navigation Drawer, I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971245/navigation-drawer-without-actionbar/20971952#20971952) SO link to create and manage Navigation Drawer.

Now i am using (Swipe to right from left - to show) and (Swipe from right to left - to hide)

How may I show/Hide Drawer using button highlighted in below screenshot:

[image]

**header_home.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout        
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/header_layout" 
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="top|center">


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textHeader"
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_header"
 />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_drawer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    />
```

**Edited:**

```
     btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);                
        }
    });
```

I know to close i have to call `drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);` but where i have to place this code ?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Grab a reference to the `DrawerLayout` and call [closeDrawer(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#closeDrawer(int)) to close it and [openDrawer(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(int)) to open it. The `int` parameter refers to the gravity. In your case it should be `GravityCompat.LEFT`/ `GravityCompat.START`, because accordingly to the screenshot you posted, your `DrawerLayout` open and close on the left.

Comment: thank you your trick worked for me, but still i don't know where to place the code to close drawer, check my Edited code

Comment: use the same button. `if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) { // close } else {// open }`

Comment: To close the navigation drawer simply call drawerLayout.closeDrawers()

Comment: consider using `Gravity.START` to support different layout directions

Comment: If you are using START or END for gravity you might want to use GravityCompat

Comment: @Ads back in 2015, there was no `GravityCompat`

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks for the edit and updating it to 2019.

Answer (score 14):

to Close Drawer:

```
drawer.CloseDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
```

to Open Drawer:

```
drawer.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
```

Answer (score 6):

To open the Drawer

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

To close the drawer

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be late for this but here is the solution you are looking for:

```
btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }                
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Sliding Drawer Menu, and you want to hide the menu when it is open (when drag from right to left). Then we have to deal with listview object ontouch listener.
The code will be like this.

```
    //((( When we drage from Right to left then menu hide ))))
    lvMenu.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) 
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    toggleMenu(v);                  
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //showtoast("up");
                    break;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }


    });

     public void toggleMenu(View v) {
    mLayout.toggleMenu();
}
```

For complete code, you can put the comment here, if you have any problem