# Is there a way to us button onclick listener to open nav drawer on android

Tags: android

I'm currently using aide to write the app 
I have alread created the Nav drawer but I don't want to open it with the toggle button in the action bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show/Hide Navigation Drawer programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583169/how-to-show-hide-navigation-drawer-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.menu_btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if(!drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        else drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
    }
});
```