# How to create a drawer without TopAppBar in Jetpack Compose - Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

So i am new to Jetpack compose and am trying to figure out how to add the drawer functionality to a button on my view.

A counterpart question that i found for my question in relation to the XML imperative approach [Navigation Drawer without Actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971245/navigation-drawer-without-actionbar)

Would love to learn about the approach to the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in many ways i guess. I will only post 2 alternatives

1- You can use Scaffold with `drawerContent` and adding your layout as this content

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val openDrawer: () -> Unit = { coroutineScope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() } }
val closeDrawer: () -> Unit = { coroutineScope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.close() } }


Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    drawerContent = {
        AppDrawer(
            currentRoute = currentRoute,
            navigateToHome = {
                currentRoute = Routes.HOME_ROUTE
                navController.popBackStack()
                navController.navigate(currentRoute)
            },
            navigateToSettings = {
                currentRoute = Routes.SETTINGS_ROUTE
                navController.popBackStack()
                navController.navigate(currentRoute)
            },
            closeDrawer = closeDrawer
        )
    },

) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Routes.HOME_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(Routes.HOME_ROUTE) {
            HomeComponent()
        }

        composable(Routes.SETTINGS_ROUTE) {
            SettingsComponent()
        }
    }
}
```

Our drawer content

```
@Composable
fun AppDrawer(
    currentRoute: String,
    navigateToHome: () -> Unit,
    navigateToSettings: () -> Unit,
    closeDrawer: () -> Unit
) {

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        DrawerHeader()
        DrawerButton(
            icon = Icons.Filled.Home,
            label = "Home",
            isSelected = currentRoute == Routes.HOME_ROUTE,
            action = {
                if (currentRoute != Routes.HOME_ROUTE) {
                    navigateToHome()
                }
                closeDrawer()
            }
        )

        DrawerButton(
            icon = Icons.Filled.Settings,
            label = "Settings",
            isSelected = currentRoute == Routes.SETTINGS_ROUTE,
            action = {
                if (currentRoute != Routes.SETTINGS_ROUTE) {
                    navigateToSettings()
                }
                closeDrawer()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

You need to set `scaffoldState` to have drawer to be able to open or close with other interactions other than drawable behavior.
`openDrawer` and `closeDrawer` lambdas are required if you need to open or close drawer like touching an item on drawer on content.

2- Using ModalDrawer

```
@Composable
private fun ModalDrawerComponent() {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val openDrawer: () -> Unit = { coroutineScope.launch { drawerState.open() } }
    val closeDrawer: () -> Unit = { coroutineScope.launch { drawerState.close() } }
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    ModalDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerContentHeader()
            Divider()
            ModelDrawerContentBody(
                selectedIndex,
                onSelected = {
                    selectedIndex = it
                },
                closeDrawer = closeDrawer
            )
        },
        content = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
//                ModalDrawerTopAppBar(openDrawer)
                ModalContent(openDrawer)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

With ModalDrawer you set your Content as you wish if you don't want to add TopAppBar you just don't add it inside content. I commented it here to display that it's not there.

You can check repo that contains implementations [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#2-9-1-side-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scaffold` and configure only the drawer in it. The composable accepts slots where you can put whatever fits your needs

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material)