# Navigation Drawer toggle button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've setup up a navigation drawer in my android App. I would like to add a button to the left but not in the action bar, because I don't have action bar. What I want to do is a button which can be taken and swiped to open the menu.

In the doc : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon I don't want to use the app icon, but my own button.

Is it possible ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17822591/1777090) might help you.

Comment: I'd like to swipe with this button, not a simple button to open.

Comment: Your goal is unclear. The Drawer already opens by dragging it, so do you just want some View as decoration? Maybe a simple mockup image would help to clarify.

Comment: Yeah : https://imageshack.com/i/excNFUOxp Is it better ? ;). Yes, like you say, it's simply a decoration to say "hey, you can swipe here !!"

Answer (score 0):

With this library you can do exactly what you want. It's easy to implement and use.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use any other library, are you sure it's not possible with a native Android code ?

Comment: i did not say "it's not possible with native android code" i did not do what you want with navigation drawer but it did same with the library i linked in my answer.