# Rotated ListFragment disappears when empty view displayed after Filter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listfragment, slidingdrawer

Just to be clear, we're talking about an XML rotated view here, not the effects of rotating the device. I have a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) that contains a ListFragment. The ListFragment implements the [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface so that users can search its contents by providing a string input through an EditText.

The relevant layout is included below. Because the SlidingDrawer class was deprecated in API 17, the source code was copied over an accessed via a local class. That's why the name of that view looks like a custom class when really it's not.

```
<com.example.echo.views.SlidingDrawer 
        android:id="@+id/left_sliding_drawer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:handle="@+id/left_handle"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:content="@+id/people_fragment_container"
        android:rotation="180">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@id/left_handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/people_tab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/people_map_tab_grey"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:contentDescription="@string/people_tab"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/people_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </com.example.echo.views.SlidingDrawer>
```

What happens is, when the users provides input and filters the list such that there are no matching results, i.e., the ListView is empty and size is 0, the entire SlidingDrawer disappears.

Some things I've noticed in trying to fix this:

I am pretty sure this is related to displaying the empty view and/or whatever layout change occurs when it is displayed. If I simply do not set an empty view for the ListFragment the issue does not occur.

I am also pretty sure the effects are related to the fact that the SlidingDrawer is being rotated by 180 degrees since, if I remove the rotation attribute, the issue also does not occur.  However, because SlidingDrawer in its default state only opened right to left, this drawer applies the XML attribute android:rotation="180" to flip the view so that it can be opened left to right. This must remain since there is other stuff on the right side of the screen that cannot be moved.

I'm not sure what is making the view disappear or where to start fixing it. I've trying fixing the child views' sizes by overriding onMeasure, onSizeChanged, and onLayout but cannot find anything that solves the issue.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: `SlidingDrawer` is deprecated. Any reason you are not using [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html). You can use `android:layout_gravity` to make it appear on the right

Comment: SlidingDrawer has a handle built in that you can pull out from the side. Also,  can only open one DrawerLayout as far as I can tell. The design here calls for a left and right drawer.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11228364/1011435

Comment: I can try that library but still doesn't answer the question of why the view is disappearing